# Graduated high school in top 10%?

Tags: phrase-usage

I have a question regarding how to write your school grades. If you want to write someone saying that you graduated high school in the top 10%, should you write it like this?

> "Graduated high school in the top 10% in class."

And if you want to use your actual place instead of using percentiles, should you write it like this?

> "Graduated high school tenth in class."

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: I'd avoid the percentage sentence because it means little or nothing if your class was small. Most employers probably want to know your grade point average (GPA) rather than your class rank. The next issue it what you're writing this for. If it's a résumé, you can say in the Education section, something like: "Ridgewood High School, Ridgewood, NJ. June 20012. Tenth in class of 247." If it's in your cover letter, perhaps "I graduated with a GPA of 3.75, and 10th in my high school class of 247."

Comment: @BillFranke - do note that in some cases, percentage matters; for example, in Texas, we had (have?) a rule that the top 10% of public high school graduates get automatic admission to the University of Texas. That number was (if I recall correctly) independent of graduating class size.

Comment: @AdamV: Yes, that's true in California too. But if the OP were applying for admission to UT or UC, there'd be no need to ask this Q. Which is why I said "most employers". If your HS had two graduates this year in your HS class at Los Huisaches (CDP) (pop: 14) & you were #2 in your class, how does that affect your chance of auto-admission to UT if your GPA was 4.0?

Comment: @BillFranke Well, surely the percentage is more meaningful than an absolute rank. If someone says "I was 10th in my class", that means something rather different if he was in a class of 3000 than if he was in a class of 10. Sure, the smaller the class size, the more random variation you might have in any given year and so the less meaningful the number. If your school has a graduating class of 10 each year, the person who was #1 this year might have been #5 if matched against last year's students. But there's nothing the student can do about his class size. I wouldn't agonize over it.

Comment: @BillFranke If my graduating class had 2 students and I was number 2 with a GPA of 3.9, I'd point on my resume "GPA: 3.9", not "bottom 50% of my class". In salesmanship -- and a resume is a form of salesmanship -- you present the information in the way that is most favorable to yourself.

Comment: Reminds me of the story of the person who was in a competition with a hated rival, and afterward boasted that he came in second while his rival was next to last. He didn't mention that they were the only two in the competition.

Comment: @BillFranke: the way the 10% rule works in California at least (possibly also in other states that have the top 10% auto-admission rule) is that they take the top 10% of graduates *in the state*. Your class size doesn't matter, because you're being compared to every other graduating senior in the state.

Comment: @Jay: Yes, good points. I suggested saying "10th in class of 247" in my 1st comment. If you're #2 of 2 & have a GPA of 3.9, you've no choice but to focus on your GPA, SATs, & other positive points. Great story! And great illustration of how language actually works when you think about it & use it to your advantage rather than merely aping what everyone else says & writes in similar situations. That's why rhetoric exists & spin doctors flourish in business & politics. Don't be like the guy in the story with the punchline that begins: "Hey, baby. Know anything about Africa? No? Let's f...."

Answer (score 2):

I would say

> I was **among the top 10%** (of the students) when I graduated high school.

and for your other question

> I **got 10th rank** or **was ranked 10th (among the students)** in my high school.

Comment: "Of/among the students" is superfluous. You wouldn't ever say "of/among the teachers", "of/among the cafeteria workers", or "of/among the stray dogs lolling around the playground". Only students graduate.

Comment: @BillFranke So are you saying that saying 'I secured the 10th rank among the 1000 students that participated in the nationwide contest' is incorrect? The reason I am asking is that I have seen it being used by people often but they all are non natives.

Comment: @JoeD: Your question has two parts. The first has to do with _I secured the 10th rank_. That doesn't sound natural to me. It's not idiomatic American English. Maybe _I took 10th place_ or _I was number 10_. Adding the bit about _of the 1000 students who participated in the contest_ is an important piece of information in this sentence if the listener doesn't know it's about a contest. But saying _I graduated 10th in my high school class_ doesn't require you to tell the listener that the other graduates were also students: that's built into the "high school class" phrase.

Comment: I had classmates who probably would not have made the top 10% of stray dogs lolling around the playground. :-)

Answer (score 2):

A more common way to write your first sentence would probably be:

> I graduated high school in the top 10% of my class.

This means that your rank was in the highest 10%, and 90% of the class was below you.

Your second sentence doesn't mean the same thing:

> I graduated high school tenth in my class.

This means that you were ranked #10 in your class (not the top 10%). It means that only and exactly 9 students were ranked higher than you, and everyone else was ranked lower than you.

Comment: Well, if your graduating class had at least 100 students, then both statements could be true. :)

Comment: The question says "if you wanted to write your actual place instead of using percentiles", so the second sentence is perfectly correct!